# Нужны ли запятые: "По всем(,) интересующим Вас(,) вопросам..."?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли здесь запятые:

> По всем(,) интересующим Вас(,)  вопросам
>   обращайтесь к нашим...

Просьба обосновать ответ.

Comment: @Виктория Ив, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

У Розенталя есть конкретное правило об этом: "Причастный оборот, стоящий после определительного, указательного или притяжательного местоимения, не отделяется запятой от этого местоимения. Пример: Ваше написанное от руки заявление с трудом удалось прочитать"

Comment: Формальное правило не позволяет охватить все частные случаи написаний, которые легко решаются путем простого анализа, например: Каждое явление имеет свои, присущие только ему, признаки. Дашу удивила доморощенность всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения. Все опоздавшие на лекцию стояли в коридоре. Все, опоздавшие на лекцию или семинар, должны написать объяснительную записку.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: "По всем интересующим Вас вопросам обращайтесь к нашим....."

Пояснение: всем интересующим Вас  - это определение + определительный оборот, которые являются  неоднородными, поэтому запятая между ними не ставится.

Обособлять оборот "интересующим Вас" для его выделения (со значением актуализации/уточнения/пояснения) не имеет смысла. В таких конструкциях это делается крайне редко.

Сравнить:"По всем вопросам, интересующим Вас,  обращайтесь к нашим....."  Здесь оборот обособляется после определяемого слова.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!